# Prolog why the following term doesn't unify?

Tags: prolog

In prolog `=` is used for unification, as far as I understand if the two terms can be matched maybe with the help if variable instantiation, they are unified.

So why the following query fails

```
?- 2+2 = 4.
```

Although 2+2 yields into 4 which is the same number as the other term.

Comment: If you're more used to imperative languages (like java or c#) then it is best to think of `2 + 2 = 4` in Prolog as `"2 + 2" == "4"`. It's only when you put `4 is 2 + 2` that Prolog will evaluate the `2 + 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What others have answered is correct, but here's a little more detail.

In Prolog, the term `2+2` is just a syntactical alternative to the term, `'+'(2, 2)`. This is a term with functor `+` and with two arguments (2 and 2). The term `2` is just an interger and has no arguments. The `=/2` operator attempts to *unify terms*. It does not perform arithmetic expression evaluation. These terms are clearly different and cannot be unified (they don't even have the same number of arguments).

There are operators in Prolog which will perform the expression evaluation. For expression equality, you can use `=:=/2` or better, as @mat points out for reasoning over integers,  you can use `#=/2`. So the following will work:

```
| ?- 2+2 =:= 4.

yes
| ?- 2+2 #= 4.

yes
| ?-
```

There is also `is/2` which will evaluate the second argument only and determine if it's value is the same as the value of the first argument. Thus the following will happen:

```
| ?- 2+2 is 4.

no
| ?- 4 is 2+2.

yes
| ?-
```

The above examples are in GNU prolog. Note that in SWI Prolog you must include the CLP(FD) library to use operators that reason over integers:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Comment: ?-  2+2 #= 4.

ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: 2+2
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  #= 4 .
On Ubuntu 22.04 swiprolog

Comment: @moueza in SWI prolog you must include the CLP(FD) module for operators such as `#=` to be recognized: `use_module(library(clpfd)).`.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the other posts, I would like to suggest `(#=)/2` as a more declarative alternative to `(is)/2` when reasoning about **integers**.

`(#=)/2` denotes **arithmetic equality** of *integer expressions*. This involves an **evaluation** step and is therefore different from just *syntactic* equality. In your case, you *expected* the former, but *got* the latter.

Usage example, with GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- 4 #= 2+2.

yes
```

The primary advantage of `(#=)/2` is that it works in *all* directions:

```
| ?- 4 #= 2+X.

X = 2
```

In contrast, we get with `(is)/2`:

```
| ?- 4 is 2+X.
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

Such problems are very common (see [instantiation-error](/questions/tagged/instantiation-error)) when beginners first learn about arithmetic, and so I recommend you start using more declarative predicates at least in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The expression on the left-hand side is not evaluated by itself. You are instead comparing the unification of strings. To compare the unification of the expression's evaluation with the right-hand side, you need to use the is/2 operator.

```
?- 4 is 2+2.
```

Compare with:

```
?- 2+2 = 2+2.
```

and

```
?- X is 2+2.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

2 + 2 = 4

the answer is no, because prolog will compare a number (4) to a formula (2+2), which are not the same.  To make it right, you need prolog to *evaluate* the formula `2 + 2` before comparing it to `4`. For that, use the `is` operator:

> The `is` operator is meant specifically for mathematical functions. The left argument has to be a variable and the right argument has to be a mathematical function with all variables instantiated.
>
> The `=` operator is used for unification of variables and can be used with any two arguments (although it will fail if the two arguments aren't the same and can't be made the same by instantiating variables a certain way) [[source]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Math,_Functions_and_Equality).

So in your example:

```
4 is 2+2
```

Will evaluate to `yes`.

Comment: `2+2 is 4` will not "evaluate to yes". It will fail.